# I want to create a custom middleware with django-soet

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-middleware

I want to create custom middleware in my project. but I am getting errors like this:

```
[  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'custommiddle.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module. ]
```

I think the problem might be my python version, I am using version **3.7**.

Here is my folder structure:

```
custommiddle/  # project name
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  wsgi.py
  cmiddle/  # app name
    middle/  # directory
      __init__.py
      middleware.py
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

**middleware.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

class StackOverflowMiddleware(object):
  def __init__(self, get_response):
      self.get_response = get_response

  def __call__(self, request):
      response = self.get_response(request)
      return response

  def process_exception(self, request, exception):
      if settings.DEBUG:
          print (exception.__class__.__name__)
          print (exception.message)
      return None
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'soet' ]
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [  'soet.middleware.StackOverFlowMiddleware' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have edit your **settings.py** properly. Because middleware part seems correct. Can you confirm that you edit your settings.py properly, like below

**settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = ...

SECRET_KEY = ...

DEBUG = ...

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'soet', # your apps
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'soet.middleware.StackOverFlowMiddleware' # your_middleware
]

.
.
.
```

Comment: everything configured properly in settings.py file . but it throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

**soet** is using python2 syntax. In Python 3, the **print** statement has been replaced with a **print()** function.

Look at the codebase at https://github.com/vitorfs/soet/blob/master/soet/middleware.py 
and you can change it to python3 syntax (Basically look at print statement only).

Visit django docs for creating middleware at : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: I solved the print statement in  soet\middleware.py. but it throws same error

Comment: Can you show the full trace of your error . Maybe some other problem exists in your application , just check it by uninstalling your middleware once .